# How to insert special characters into a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string named 'string1',

```
string1 = "Mr. Jorge Alexa Narvaez is a former Canadian cricketer and a politician.";
```

And I have another string named 'string2' which **only have** strings surrounded by '`<NOUN> and </NOUN>`' tags separated by a space.

```
string2 = "<NOUN>Jorge Alexa Narvaez</NOUN> <NOUN>Canadian</NOUN>";
```

Note that second string can have any no of noun tagged words(based on the 'string1',eg: if string1 has 3 nouns, string2 will have same 3 nouns surrounded by noun tags)
I want to add  tags to the 'string1' and make string1 as follows,

```
string1 = "Mr. <NOUN>Jorge Alexa Narvaez</NOUN> is a former <NOUN>Canadian</NOUN> cricketer and a politician.";
```

**Simply I just want to replace 'Jorge Alexa Narvaez' and 'Canadian' with `<NOUN>Jorge Alexa Narvaez</NOUN> and <NOUN>Canadian</NOUN>`**

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: you need to break the code..you cant do it entirely in regex

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this? If you can please provide the code

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as follows,

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<NOUN>(.*?)</NOUN>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string2);
    while(m.find()) {
        string1= string1.replaceAll(m.group(1),m.group(0));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1. Is string2 generated by some library that you don't have handle on?
2. will string2 contain only "<NOUN>" tags or any other tags?

A crude way to do it, if it only contains  tags, is

1. split string2 on (<NOUN>|</NOUN>). The result is an array that
   contains nouns from string1 (and empty spaces).
2. iterate through the array, ignore the empty strings and replace the non-empty strings in string1 with noun embedded between "" and "".

Sample code that does this:

```
{
    String string1 = "Mr. Jorge Alexa Narvaez is a former Canadian cricketer and a politician.";
    String string2 = "<NOUN>Jorge Alexa Narvaez</NOUN> <NOUN>Canadian</NOUN>";
    String[] list = string2.split("(<NOUN>|</NOUN>)");
    for (String str : list)
    {
        if (str.trim().isEmpty())
        {
            continue;
        }
        string1 = string1.replace(str, "<NOUN>" + str + "</NOUN>");
    }
    System.out.println(string1);
}
```

There are much better, organized ways to do this, if you have more details on how string2 is generated.

Comment: I did it in my own way, Please check the answer and let me know if there is any error, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Its in c#...hope you convert it properly to java

```
string s="<NOUN>Jorge Alexa Narvaez</NOUN> <NOUN>Canadian</NOUN>";
string s1="Mr. Jorge Alexa Narvaez is a former Canadian cricketer and a politician.";

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(s,@"(?<=<NOUN>).*?(?=</NOUN>)"))
s1=Regex.Replace(s1,m.Value,"<NOUN>$0<NOUN>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code and it worked just fine. You can optimize it by using Stringbuffer instead of String class.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class StringManipulation {

    String temp = "<NOUN>Nitin<NOUN> <NOUN>test<NOUN>";
    String finalString ="HeI am Nitin and I want to test seomthing";


    public void doIt(){

        StringTokenizer x = new StringTokenizer(temp, " ");
        while (x.hasMoreTokens()){

            String token = x.nextToken();

            String findword = token.replaceAll("<NOUN>", "");
            String findword1 = findword.replaceAll("</NOUN>", "");

            String modifiedString = finalString.replaceFirst(findword1, "<NOUN>"+findword1+"</NOUN>");
            this.finalString = modifiedString;

    }
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new StringManipulation().doIt();

    }

}
```